# For loop python multiple checks

Tags: python

If I have strings like following:

```
my_string(0) = Your FUTURE looks good.
my_string(1) = your future doesn't look good.
```

I want to print both the lines with the following:

```
for stings in my_string:
   if 'FUTURE' or 'future' in string:
      print 'Success!'
```

my `if` loop works for the first condition with `FUTURE`, however, the second comparison with `future` doesn't work. What is the reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use:

```
if 'FUTURE' in string or 'future' in string:
```

or simply:

```
if 'future' in string.lower()
```

Why this failed:

```
if 'FUTURE' or 'future' in string:
```

is actually equivalent to :

```
True or ('future' in string)   # bool('FUTURE') --> True
```

as the first condition is always **True** so the next condition is never checked .In fact your if-condition is always **True** no matter what string contains.

A non-empty string is always `True` in python and `or` operation short-circuits as soon as a True value is found.

```
>>> strs1 = "your future doesn't look good."
>>> strs2 = "Your FUTURE looks good."
>>> 'FUTURE' or 'future' in strs1
'FUTURE'
>>> 'Foobar' or 'future' in strs1
'Foobar'
>>> 'Foobar' or 'cat' in strs1
'Foobar'
>>> '' or 'cat' in strs1    #  empty string is a falsey value,
False                       #  so now it checks the  next condition
```

Note that :

```
>>> 'FUTURE' in 'FOOFUTURE'
True
```

is `True`, as `in` operator looks for sub-strings not exact word match.

Use either `regex` or `str.split` to handle such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement should be read as

```
if 'FUTURE':
  if 'future' in string :
    print ...
```

Non-empty strings are evaluated as `True` so `if 'FUTURE'` is redundant

You want:

```
if 'future' in string.lower():
  print ...
```

Comment: your first snippet would be accurate if the line had been `if 'FUTURE' and 'future' in string...`. it's more like `if 'FUTURE':[code] elif 'future' in string: [same code]`